# Cannot find the brightness controller

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, brightness

The default brightness controller is supposed to be visible here:

[image: brightness-controller-missing]

But it is not visible.

Following is my system configuration:
[image: system-configuration]

I have also a `NVIDIA RTX 2060 Super` GPU. Following is its configuration:
[image: nvidia-smi]

But the surprising fact is that:

1. I found this problem even when I was using `Ubuntu 20.04` and now I have to same problem with even with `Ubuntu 22.04.3`.
2. The problem I only found on my desktop. I have another laptop where there is **NO NVIDIA CARD**, and that doesn't have this problem at all. Although, the laptop also has the same operating system installed. I suspect this problem is somehow related to the `NVIDIA` Driver.
3. For now, I try to adjust the brightness with the following command `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.7`. But, this solution is temporary, and even worse, the brightness again becomes 100% automatically (especially, after every restart, or sometimes just after opening any arbitrary application the brightness automatically becomes high).

NB:

- I have already tried 3rd party apps (`sudo apt-get install brightness-controller`) but didn't fix the real problem. Brightness still becomes high automatically. See here: [Brightness increases automatically after a while.](https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/issues/193)
- I preferably want the default brightness controller which is missing (first snapshot).

How to fix that?

Comment: Consider using the Nvidia X Server Settings app.

Comment: Dear downvoter, justify the reason for down voting. I shall update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an external monitor,

1. You can try to increase or decrease brightness from monitor menu. Just click the menu button on monitor. This would adjust the same brightness in the windows (if you are using dual boot).
2. Additionally, if your keyboard has brightness controller keys, generally Function keys at the very top. Sometimes you have to enable function lock (Fn lock) to use these keys.

Moreover, this issue has nothing to do with graphic card drivers.